# Why can you use the @param tag with classes in Java?

Tags: java

In looking at Javadoc comments in a Java API, I see that some classes have the @param tag in their doc comments. I thought classes didn't accept parameters -- just methods and constructors. So why would there be @param tags for a class?

Comment: Adding an example will elaborate more.

Comment: It's for Javadocs, no? What `@param` are you talking about?

Comment: Classes don't accept parameters, but they might be labeling the constructor's parameters rather than the class

Comment: Indicates generic types most likely. `class Foo<T> {}` Here it is appropriate to describe why exactly is there a generic parameter and what it supposed to be.

Comment: What do you think `String` is in `List<String>`?

Comment: Ahh, yes, it is a generic type like bali182 indicates. I will look into this more. (Sorry, I would post a code sample but this is a piece of code from work so it's firewalled.)